# Groupwise data inside gridview in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

My table is

```
ID  Name    Department
1   A           1
2   B           1
3   C           1
4   D           2
5   E           2
6   F           3
7   G           3
8   H           3
9   I           3
10  J           4
11  K           4
```

I want to bind the data inside gridview with the `fieldset` according to the department.

something like this

```
**1**
A
B
C
**2**
D
E
**3**
F
G
H
I
**4**
J
K
```

Please help me to create this.

Comment: you can use Datatable in place of grid refer this https://www.datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/row_grouping.html